# MySQL like query not working?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a successful connection made in PDO to my MySQL database and I am currently trying to get it to query the database for itmes LIKE the search query.

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');

function doSearch() {
    $output = '';
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE name LIKE :searchq or description LIKE :searchq or content LIKE :searchq";

    global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":searchq",$searchq,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
 if($count == 0) {
            $output = 'No results found, buddy.';
        } else {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $eName = $row['name'];
                $eDesc = $row['description'];
                $eCont = $row['content'];
                $id = $row['id'];
                $elvl = $row['level'];
                $ehp = $row['hp'];

                $output .= '<tr><td><a href="http://ccc.aaaa.whatever/' .$eName. '" onclick="document.linkform.submit();">'.$eName.'</a></td><td>'.$eDesc.'</td><td>'.$elvl.'</td><td>'.$ehp.'</td></tr>';
            }
        }            

    return $output;
    }
 }
?>
```

I am struggling to get it to search. Unless the query exactly matches only the name, it doesn't show any results.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE` operator does not do partial matches unless specifically instructed to. Perhaps you meant to prepend/append a `%` wildcard symbol to the search string:

```
$searchq = '%' . $searchq . '%';
```

Comment: I tried that, and that actually stopped the search from working at all.

When I think about it, the trouble could be with the 'or' statement. Being that it will only search names right now.

Comment: Really? Can you post the code you used? The `OR` should be ok

Comment: Oh now that you've edited your answer, I see that I may of missed something, let me give this a shot.

Comment: Nope, that breaks it. 

You can try the page out yourself, http://seersvillage.com/v1.3/search.php. Search for zombie, which also has Undead in it's description. Search for undead, and zombie doesn't show. 

I also added another entry, search for Meep. Nothing at all comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong in the SQL text of the query.

The simplest explanation is that the SQL you are expecting to be sent to the database isn't what is being sent.

I suggest you give this a try:

use *unique* bind variable names in the statement, use each bind variable only once.

There used to be a bug in PDO with named bind variables (not sure if that's fixed of not. Under the covers, the named bind parameters were getting converted to positional notation, and when the same bind variable two or more times, the query being sent to MySQL wasn't what we expected.

For example:

```
 $sql = "SELECT e.* 
           FROM entries e
          WHERE e.name        LIKE :searchq1
             OR e.description LIKE :searchq2
             OR e.content     LIKE :searchq3";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":searchq1",$searchq,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":searchq2",$searchq,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(":searchq3",$searchq,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

When we encountered the problem, we weren't using server side prepared statements, just regular client side prepares; the SQL sent to the server included literals, not placeholders. Turning on the general_log in MySQL allowed us to see the actual SQL statements that were being sent to the database.

You might be encountering the same problem. But I'd recommend this as a step in debugging the problem, at least to verify it isn't the problem.

Comment: Hi there, what would SELECT e.* do opposed to SELECT *?

Comment: ALSO: I've figured out that it's not showing results that have a space in them. I thought that's what preg_replace was for? So maybe the issue could be that it's getting stuck there?

Comment: @Jack Miller: `SELECT e.*` and `SELECT *` are exactly the same thing in the context of this query; there's no difference.  The result from the `preg_replace` is something you could echo or printf. You also might try `bindValue` in place of `bindParam`. Unfortunately, `debugDumpParams` doesn't show the actual values of the parameters, just the placeholders and their types. Also note that `foo LIKE 'bar'` is the same as `foo = 'bar'`. To get a wildcard match, you'd need to include the wildcards `_` or `%`  e.g. `foo LIKE 'bar%'` to find foo starting with 'bar'.